# Opengl drawing half circle

Tags: c++, c

I am trying to draw half a circle; When I run my code I don't get any errors but nothing prints out. Can someone please let me know what I am doing wrong? I tried changing the window position but no luck.

```
#include<GL/glut.h>
#include <math.h>

void DrawHalfCircle()
 {
     glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
     glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
     glColor4f(1, 0, 0, 0);
     int number = 20; //number of vertices,
     float radius = 0.4f; // radius of the circle
     float twopi = 2.0f*3.14159f;
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); //operate in model view
    glLoadIdentity();//after every matrixmode, loadidentity is used.
    glTranslatef(0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f); //to move the position of circle towards +ve x axis
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN); //drawing circle using triangle fan
    glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); //blue in color
    glVertex2f(0.0f, 0.0f); //placing at the origin
    for (int i = 0; i <= 21; i++)
           glVertex2f(radius*cosf(i*twopi / number), radius*sinf(i*twopi / number));
     glEnd();
     glFlush();
}
```

The main

```
 int main()

{
       glutInit(&argc, argv);  //initialize glut
       glutInitWindowSize(640, 480); //width and height
       glutInitWindowPosition(0, 50); //bottom-left corner
       glutCreateWindow("drawing half a circle"); 
       glutDisplayFunc(DrawHalfCircle);
       glutMainLoop(); //loops itself again and again
      return 0;
```

}

Comment: What is you glut version and what version of gcc/g++ are you using? (Also your compiling in C++ I am assuming? If so, please don't use the C tag as this only leads to confusion. )

Comment: Do you see a blank window, or nothing at all?  You may need to call https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node12.html or glutPostRedisplay (sometimes the first display call doesn't trigger properly).

Comment: I see a blank window.

Comment: If you leave the modelview matrix at the origin, do you see anything?

Answer (score 1):

those 2 functions draw 2 half circles, 1 is full and another is hollow.(in c++), your main is correct i guess.

```
void drawLeftCircle()   // the filled one
{
    float radius = 70;
    float twoPI = 2 * PI;

    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);

    for (float i = PI; i <= twoPI; i += 0.001)
        glVertex2f((sin(i)*radius), (cos(i)*radius));

    glEnd();
    glFlush();
}


void drawRightHalfCircle()  // the empty one
{
    float radius = 70;
    float twoPI = 2 * PI;

    glBegin(GL_POINTS);

    for (float i = 0.0; i <= twoPI / 2; i += 0.001)
        glVertex2f((sin(i)*radius), (cos(i)*radius));

    glEnd();
    glFlush();
}
```